# Why are VB.NET COM servers so much slower when operating on passed-in arrays?

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba, dll, com

Background: I'm using a VB.NET COM DLL server in an Excel VBA macro. The VBA macro makes a single call to a subroutine in the DLL, passing in an array. In my tests, reading from the array in the VB.NET code is significantly slower (10x) than reading from an array created locally in the VB.NET code, even though they have the same type. The difference persists regardless of whether the VB.NET subroutine takes the array argument ByRef or ByVal.

The code, Excel/VBA side:

```
Dim x As MyDllTest.MyDllTestClass
Set x = New MyDllTest.MyDllTestClass
Dim arr(10) 
Call x.someSub(arr)
```

VB.NET side:

```
Public Class MyDllTestClass
    Sub someSub(ByRef arr) ' Changing to ByVal changes nothing
        Dim i
        For i = 1 To 10000000 ' huge number to show speed difference
            Dim x = arr(1 + i Mod 10) ' some useless read
        Next i
    End Sub
End Class
```

I've seen other questions where people complain about the slowness of VB.NET COM DLLs but usually it's due to interop overhead across many calls to the DLL. In my case there is only one call so that's not it.

At first I thought that the slowness could be caused by VBA passing in some strange array type that's not native to VB.NET and operations on it are slower. But `MsgBox(TypeName(arr))` indicates that VB.NET sees `arr` as just another `Object()` array (or `Integer()`, `Double()`, etc. depending on how `arr` is initialized in the VBA code).

Then I thought that maybe the `ByRef` forces some clunky interop between the client and server, but after changing to `ByVal` -- which I thought would copy the array, thereby sidestepping any memory sharing issues and making it functionally equivalent to a local one -- it is still just as slow. Doing the same 10 million reads on a local `Object()` array in the VB.NET code is 10x faster. Huh?

If anyone could help me understand what's going on I'd really appreciate it. Sorry if I'm being stupid here (hopefully it's that simple); this is my first week working in a Windows environment after a 10 year hiatus and I'm new to all the technologies involved (VBA/VB.NET/DLLs/COM). Thanks.

Comment: You are using late binding in the .Net code.  As defined `arr` is an Object that holds an array.  This is fine, If you cast it to an Object array first and then iterate that typed array, you should see a huge improvement. i.e  `Dim arr2 as Object()=Ctype(arr, Object())`

Comment: Yes, it is "some strange array type".  It is a SAFEARRAY, a purely unmanaged animal, the storage for the array is owned by Excel.  It comes with a protocol that ensures this can all work correctly, even though the VB.NET compiler has no idea whatsoever that this is not a CLR array, it isn't cheap.  If you want it faster then just create your own array and assign *arr* at the end.  You still pay for the conversion, but at least it can be done in one whack, bypassing the protocol.